# Input/Output Error on Create-React-App in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, create-react-app

I'm trying to dockerize my `create-react-app` development environment and preserving hot reloads. According to most guides (and [this guy](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3969)), the most direct way is `docker run -p 3000:3000 -v "$(pwd):/var/www" -w "/var/www" node npm start` in the project folder.

However, I'm getting this error instead:

```
$ docker run -p 3000:3000 -v "$(pwd):/var/www" -w "/var/www" node npm start

> my-app@0.1.0 start /var/www
> react-scripts start

sh: 1: react-scripts: Input/output error
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-04-02T06_55_22_257Z-debug.log
```

I'm running on Windows. I believe mounting the volume might have some permission issues leading to the input/output error, but testing various settings didn't work out. I'm honestly stumped. All I want is to run my app in Docker with hot reload for development.

Comment: Why "in Docker"?  Doubly true for a front-end application, where the actual code runs in your browser and can't take advantage of things like Docker networking.  I'd recommend installing Node on your host if you haven't already and use an actual local development environment.

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze, this is primarily to standardize the development environment for all devs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As it turns out](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/how-to-create-react-app-with-docker), setting up `create-react-app` in docker takes a little more work.

The primary issue is that *mounted volumes are not available in the build step*, so when `node npm start` runs the mounted project files technically don't exist yet.

As such, you need to copy over and install the project first to let it run the first time before the volume mounts. Hot reloading works normally afterwards.

Here's my final working setup:

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
  create-react-app:
    build:
      context: create-react-app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      - NODE_PATH=/node_modules
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    volumes:
      - ./create-react-app:/create-react-app
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:alpine

# Extend PATH
ENV PATH=$PATH:/node_modules/.bin

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /client

# Copy project files for build
ADD . .

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Run create-react-app server
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```